# Unused Repository Directories in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH from using rosws

Tags: ros, rosws, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a small issue with my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.

I am going through the [ROS Beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials), and I notice that I have some extra directories on my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH that don't actually exist.

The problem arose when I was doing step 3 of the [overlays tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays).  I specified the wrong parameters in my rosws set command.  It still added the local directory to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, but the local repository/directory does not exist.

In other words, this is my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:
/home/developer/fuerte_workspace/clearpath_common:/home/developer/fuerte_workspace/husky:/home/developer/fuerte_workspace/clearpath:/home/developer/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

The entries that end in "clearpath" and "husky" were erroneous attempts and do not exist locally.  Is there some sort of "rosws unset" command or some other way that I can clean-up my path?

Thank you for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41792/unused-repository-directories-in-ros_package_path-from-using-rosws/) by [David Kaczynski](https://answers.ros.org/users/2982/david-kaczynski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use rosws remove.

Or you can always remove entries from your .rosinstall file manually.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1